# How to fit the isotope box in the next row when resizing?

Tags: jquery, css

Can you help me with this? I am creating a page with isotope effects. And my problem is I don't get the exact layout I want. In my isotope I have a big box, normal and small. In my example I have a big box in the first column. Now I added 4 normal box.

What I want is like this:

[image]

And what I got is like this:

[image]

How can I fit the 2 boxes below?

Here's a bit of my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="isotope js-isotope" data-isotope-options='{ "layoutMode": "fitRows", "itemSelector": ".item" }'>

      <div class="item wbig"></div>
      <div class="item wnormal"></div>
      <div class="item wnormal"></div>
      <div class="item wnormal"></div>
      <div class="item wnormal"></div>

    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.isotope {
  background: #DDD;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* clear fix */
.isotope:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- .item ---- */

.isotope .item {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #0D8;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.7);
}

.item.wbig { width: 380px; height: 380px; }
.item.wnormal { width: 190px; height: 190px; }
.item.wsmall { width: 95px; height: 95px; }
```

**JS**

```
 $('.isotope').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    masonry: {
      columnWidth: 100
    }
  });
```

I want to fit the boxes exactly when I resize my browser.

That's all guys thanks. :)

Here's some fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rochellecanale/s8r1sta3/

Comment: You need to account for your border in your item widths and heights

Comment: i dont get the problem , you will get the layout you want once the window width gets less , this is a typical screenshot from your fiddle http://imgur.com/BNyo9Jv , please clarify your issue so i can help you.

Comment: @ProllyGeek, try to maximize the browser. You will see the blocks are not fitting below the other boxes

Comment: @Jerielle it makes sense , there is a space so boxes will fit to that space , can you draw what you are expecting ?

Comment: you will see what I need to get. I posted an image on the top. :)

Comment: do you want to see big box with the 4 ones beside it , even if the window gets shrinked ?

Comment: yes, then If i resize it to much more smaller the small boxes will move below. :)